# how to search for an image in a group of images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, sift

I am new to image processing. I want to do it using Python.

Suppose I have an image X, Which technologies should I go for to search my image in a group of images.

In the uploaded images, suppose I have to search the image with the fox is there or not in the group of images.

[image: The single image]

[image: The Group of images]

Comment: What format your *AI rules* have? Give at least an example. Are you using [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/) or what?

Comment: Then edit your question and show an example of rule....